# Use cmap with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I have a developed python program for some image processing.
I am trying to get the colored sketch of an image using `cmap`.

```py
plt.imshow(invert, cmap='Blues')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Pencil-Sketch', size=20)
```

[image: This is the output with matplotlib.]
But I am a bit confused when developing the working application with OpenCV.

my try:

```py
dst_sketch, dst_color_sketch = cv2.pencilSketch(opencv_image, sigma_s=50, sigma_r=0.07, shade_factor=0.08)

invert = cv2.bitwise_not(dst_sketch)

newimage = cv2.applyColorMap(invert, cv2.COLORMAP_AUTUMN)
```

[image: This is the output with OpenCV colormap]
But in OpenCV, any `matplotlib`-like colors are not available in the colormap.

Is there a way to achieve the same as using `matplotlib` when using OpenCV?

Comment: @Bilal Yes. The image at the bottom is gained by using the colormap in opencv. But it does not give the same output like in matplotlib. As you can see, in matplotlib, I can get the output in a plain color keeping a good difference between the ojects and the background.  But it is not achieved in opencv.

Comment: maybe because it is not the same colormap, there is a [way in opencv](https://learnopencv.com/applycolormap-for-pseudocoloring-in-opencv-c-python) to define your own color map, but I'm not sure how to get that colormap from matplotlib.